# How do I redirect to a new page in a FreeMarker template?

Tags: freemarker, magnolia

I'm using a custom Magnolia forms module (built internally at my company). When the user successfully submits the form, I want to redirect the user to a success page.

This could be done in the module itself. However, if the user does not successfully submit the form (e.g. missing required fields), I need to display error messaging.

For this reason, I need to use FreeMarker to implement the redirect.

How do I redirect to a new page in a FreeMarker template?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the send redirect method. For example:

```
${ctx.response.sendRedirect("http://google.com")!}
```

**References**

- [Rendering context objects](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Rendering+context+objects#Renderingcontextobjects-ctx)
- [`WebContext.getResponse`](https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/service/local/repositories/magnolia.public.releases/archive/info/magnolia/magnolia-core/6.1/magnolia-core-6.1-javadoc.jar/!/info/magnolia/context/WebContext.html#getResponse--)
- [`HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect-java.lang.String-)